# what is the difference between node and nodejs version being shown in my terminal ubuntu 17

Tags: command-line, versions, nodejs

When I type `node -v` result: `v.10.8.0`, `npm -v` result: `v 6.2.0.` and finally `nodejs -v` result: `v.6.14.2`. I read in other forum saying that node and nodejs are same. If it's true, did I installed two different version of node? Is there really a difference between nodejs and node or both are same.

Comment: Please note that both 17.xx [Ubuntu releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) are [EOL](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) now. You should upgrade soon.

Comment: so I am supposed to remove nodejs and what is the right way of doing it @karel

Comment: Some people say there is no right or wrong way of doing it because you can have both node and nodejs installed alongside each other. node is better for me because it's more up-to-date and the node snap package lets you install multiple versions of node and then switch between versions without needing to install any additional tools with `sudo snap refresh node --channel=name-of-channel`

Comment: I done a ` sudo apt-get purge nodejs ` and it got removed which I understood when I checked for ` nodejs -v ` which returned ` bash: /usr/bin/nodejs: No such file or directory `.